# Haskell - Trying to apply a function to lines of multiple numbers

Tags: string, parsing, haskell

I am new to Haskell and I am trying to apply a function (gcd) to input on standard in, which is line separated and each line contains no less or more than two numbers. Here is an example of my input:

```
3
10 4
1 100
288 240
```

I am currently breaking up each line into a tuple of both numbers, but I am having trouble figuring out how to separate these tuples and apply a function to them. Here is what I have so far:

```
import Data.List

main :: IO ()
main = do
  n <- readLn :: IO Int
  content <- getContents
  let  
    points = map (\[x, y] -> (x, y)). map (map (read::String->Int)). map words. lines $ content
    ans = gcd (fst points :: Int) (snd points :: Int)
  print ans
```

Any information as two a good place to start looking for this answer would be much appreciated. I have read through the Learning Haskell tutorial and have not found any information of this particular problem.

Comment: Try writing a pure function `f :: String -> Int`, that takes a line of your input and calculates the gcd first. In a second step apply that function to the input inside `main`. Also take a look at `uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> ((a, b) -> c)` from the Prelude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pretty close. There is no reason to convert to a tuple or list of tuples before calling `gcd`.

```
main = do 
  contents <- getContents 
  print $ map ((\[x,y] -> gcd (read x) (read y)) . words) . lines $ contents
```

All the interesting stuff is between `print` and `contents`. `lines` will split the contents into lines. `map (...)` applies the function to each line. `words` splits the line into words. `\[x,y] -> gcd (read x) (read y)` will match on a list of two strings (and throw an error otherwise - not good practice in general but fine for a simple program like this), read those strings as `Integer`s and compute their GCD.

If you want to make use of lazy IO, in order to print each result after you enter each line, you can change it as follows.

```
main = do 
  contents <- getContents 
  mapM_ (print . (\[x,y] -> gcd (read x) (read y)) . words) . lines $ contents
```

Comment: You need to skip the first line which only consists of a single number of consequent entries.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the quick responses. I see exactly what this is doing now and I will also have to look at uncurry in the prelude.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can do it in a more imperative style:

```
import Control.Monad

main = do
    n <- readLn
    replicateM_ n $ do
        [x, y] <- (map read . words) `liftM` getLine
        print $ gcd x y
```